# two returns in one function for laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, api

Is it true that in laravel api the first return will break the function and won't let it continue executing the rest of the function?

I have this function

```
public function get(Request $request)
{ 
    $users = User::doesntHave('reservations')->get();
    if ($users) {
       return Response::json($users);
 }
     // do something here if no users attached with reservation and do 
    // return Response::json($users);
}
```

when I do this I get no data! What is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is to check if result is empty or not:

```
if (!$users->isEmpty()) {
    return Response::json($users);
}

return Response::json('There is no result');
```

And yes, you can return response only once.

Comment: Thank you! So if I do `if ($users->isEmpty()){

            return response()->json($users);

        }` it's the same thing, how can I check if there is data and if not I want to perform another code ?

Comment: It should be `if (!$users->isEmpty())`. Look at the code in my answer. If result is not empty, it returns it. If it's empty it returns serialized string.

Comment: Alexey, reading the original question again, I think he wants to `Response::json($users);` in both cases. So maybe just leave the return at the bottom and if `$users->isEmpty` do the "something"

Comment: thanks!! what's the difference between this and my code in my comment ? Just curious

Answer (score 1):

This is not exclusive to Laravel, but yes. A `return` statement [per definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) will return to the caller of the function immediately, so nothing else after it will be executed.

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.

Comment: how come in my signup function I have   `if(!$user->id) {
            return $this->response->error('could_not_create_user', 500);
        }

        if($hasToReleaseToken) {
            return $this->login($request);
        }` and it's working

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it's working" because it just does what you instructed to do! if your first conditional runs, the second won't run. Or if the second runs, the first was not ran

Comment: But in my original question I try to see if the first conditional runs and if not it will go to the second conditional. It only checks the first and skips the rest

Comment: That's because your first conditional was always matching. I don't understand about Laravel, but by reading the other answer I suppose `$users` will be an object thus it will always be true